# How to remap array only on changes?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have component **Page** which contains components **Editor** and **Preview**.

**Page** contains array **items**.

```
[
    {
        value: 0,
        text: 'Item 1'
    },
    ...
]
```

Array **items** is passed to **Editor** & **Preview** like this:

```
<editor  [items]="items"></editor>
<preview [items]="items"></preview>
```

Editor can add/delete/edit/reorder items.

Issue is preview needs this array in another format.

```
[
    {
        index: 0,
        label: 'Item 1'
    },
    ...
]
```

If I do like this

```
getRadioItems(): any[] {
    const items = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
        items.push({ index: this.items[i].value,
                     label: this.items[i].text });
    }
    return items;
}
```

and then

```
<radio-list [radioItems]="getRadioItems()"></radio-list>
```

It refreshes radio list hundreds times per second. You can't even change value because it will be reset on every refresh.

If it were without remapping - it would work fine.

What is correct way to remap **items** to **radioItems** in such case?

Comment: First I can think of - create a getRadioItem prop, then an Observable which maps your array into the desired one. On every array change emit `obs.next(this.items.slice())`; subscribe to observable and inside subscription getRadioItem = incoming data. There're probably simpler solutions though.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I will think about it. But I am not sure if it will work for more complicated structure. Which is more complicated in my case, I just simplified it for question to be easy to understand. Maybe I should just create separate component for preview which works with same data format I already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is stupid solution, but it works.

```
getRadioItems(): any[] {
    const newJson = JSON.stringify(this.items);
    if (this.json === newJson) {
        return this.cachedItems;
    }

    this.json = newJson;
    this.cachedItems = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
        this.cachedItems.push({ index: this.items[i].value,
                                label: this.items[i].text });
    }
    return this.cachedItems;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` of the preview component to `OnPush`? Then change detection should only be run when the `@Input() items` is updated.

Comment: I didn't, I will look into it.